# Device Driver IOCTL pass int

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I have written a device driver and need to pass an int value to it. Am using copy_from_user() for this. Here is what I have done so far,

```
#define MY_MAGIC 'G'
#define TEST_IOCTL _IO(MY_MAGIC, 0)
#define PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE _IOW(MY_MAGIC, 1, int )
#define TEST_IOCTL_ONE _IO(MY_MAGIC, 2)


int major;

int device_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg){

int ret, SIZE;

switch(cmd){

    case TEST_IOCTL:
        printk("NO argument IOCTL called\n");
        break;

    case PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE:
            printk("Inside PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE\n");
        ret = copy_from_user(SIZE, arg, sizeof(int));
        if(ret < 0){
            printk("Error in PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE\n");
            return -1;  
        }
        printk("Struct Array Size : %d\n",SIZE);
        break;

    case TEST_IOCTL_ONE:
        printk("NO argument IOCTL_ONE called\n");
        break;

    default :
        return -ENOTTY;
}

return 0;

}
```

When I call the `TEST_IOCTL` & `TEST_IOCTL_ONE` the module works properly. However when I call `PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE` the system freezes.

Userspace code is this,

```
if(ioctl(fd, PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE, 10) < 0){
    perror("PASS_STRUCT_ARRAY_SIZE : ");
        return -1;
}
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should never pass an `int` via an `ioctl`, because it may be a different size in kernel vs userspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. Since the argument is an integer you should just use it without `copy_from_user`:

```
SIZE = arg;
```

You only need `copy_from_user` when the argument is a pointer.

Comment: Thanks :) the new one works..actually your previous answer was helpful I want to pass(next step) a struct from user space the memory address issue is helpful :)